# Mapbox and Parse iOS Api compatibility

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, mapbox

I am writing a swift app with Mapbox and Parse Api supports. I installed Mapbox SDK 3.0.0 by CocoaPods and set up environment using [this guide](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/#cocoapods) provided by their website and everything works fine. However, when I was using CocoaPods to add Parse iOS framework by [this guide](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/native/new), something went wrong: my app crashes at the beginning of launching with error shown below. But the strange thing is this crash only happens while I was testing this app on simulator, it works well and functional on actual device. Can anybody help me to solve this issue? Thanks

```
    CoreFoundation`CFStringCompare:
    0x10a2d3590 <+0>:   pushq  %rbp
    0x10a2d3591 <+1>:   movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x10a2d3594 <+4>:   pushq  %r15
    0x10a2d3596 <+6>:   pushq  %r14
    0x10a2d3598 <+8>:   pushq  %r12
    0x10a2d359a <+10>:  pushq  %rbx
    0x10a2d359b <+11>:  movq   %rdx, %r14
    0x10a2d359e <+14>:  movq   %rsi, %r15
    0x10a2d35a1 <+17>:  movq   %rdi, %rbx
    0x10a2d35a4 <+20>:  testq  %rbx, %rbx
    0x10a2d35a7 <+23>:  js     0x10a2d3613               ; <+131>
->  0x10a2d35a9 <+25>:  movq   (%rbx), %rax
    0x10a2d35ac <+28>:  testq  %rax, %rax
    0x10a2d35af <+31>:  je     0x10a2d35f1               ; <+97>
    0x10a2d35b1 <+33>:  leaq   0x3551b8(%rip), %rcx      ; __CFConstantStringClassReferencePtr
    0x10a2d35b8 <+40>:  cmpq   (%rcx), %rax
    0x10a2d35bb <+43>:  je     0x10a2d35f1               ; <+97>
    0x10a2d35bd <+45>:  movq   0x34e3c4(%rip), %rcx      ; __kCFStringTypeID
    0x10a2d35c4 <+52>:  xorl   %r12d, %r12d
    0x10a2d35c7 <+55>:  cmpq   $0x3ff, %rcx
    0x10a2d35ce <+62>:  ja     0x10a2d35db               ; <+75>
    0x10a2d35d0 <+64>:  leaq   0x353199(%rip), %rdx      ; __CFRuntimeObjCClassTable
    0x10a2d35d7 <+71>:  movq   (%rdx,%rcx,8), %r12
    0x10a2d35db <+75>:  cmpq   %r12, %rax
    0x10a2d35de <+78>:  je     0x10a2d35f1               ; <+97>
    0x10a2d35e0 <+80>:  testb  $0x1, %al
    0x10a2d35e2 <+82>:  je     0x10a2d3613               ; <+131>
    0x10a2d35e4 <+84>:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
    0x10a2d35e7 <+87>:  callq  0x10a4548a8               ; symbol stub for: object_getClass
    0x10a2d35ec <+92>:  cmpq   %r12, %rax
    0x10a2d35ef <+95>:  jne    0x10a2d3613               ; <+131>
    0x10a2d35f1 <+97>:  movb   0x8(%rbx), %cl
    0x10a2d35f4 <+100>: movb   %cl, %al
    0x10a2d35f6 <+102>: andb   $0x5, %al
    0x10a2d35f8 <+104>: movzbl %al, %eax
    0x10a2d35fb <+107>: andb   $0x60, %cl
    0x10a2d35fe <+110>: cmpl   $0x4, %eax
    0x10a2d3601 <+113>: jne    0x10a2d3628               ; <+152>
    0x10a2d3603 <+115>: leaq   0x10(%rbx), %rax
    0x10a2d3607 <+119>: testb  %cl, %cl
    0x10a2d3609 <+121>: je     0x10a2d360e               ; <+126>
    0x10a2d360b <+123>: movq   (%rax), %rax
    0x10a2d360e <+126>: movzbl (%rax), %ecx
    0x10a2d3611 <+129>: jmp    0x10a2d3636               ; <+166>
    0x10a2d3613 <+131>: movq   0x342b1e(%rip), %rsi      ; "length"
    0x10a2d361a <+138>: movq   %rbx, %rdi
    0x10a2d361d <+141>: callq  *0x355bd5(%rip)           ; (void *)0x000000010c3ea800: objc_msgSend
    0x10a2d3623 <+147>: movq   %rax, %rcx
    0x10a2d3626 <+150>: jmp    0x10a2d3636               ; <+166>
    0x10a2d3628 <+152>: testb  %cl, %cl
    0x10a2d362a <+154>: je     0x10a2d3632               ; <+162>
    0x10a2d362c <+156>: movq   0x18(%rbx), %rcx
    0x10a2d3630 <+160>: jmp    0x10a2d3636               ; <+166>
    0x10a2d3632 <+162>: movq   0x10(%rbx), %rcx
    0x10a2d3636 <+166>: xorl   %edx, %edx
    0x10a2d3638 <+168>: xorl   %r9d, %r9d
    0x10a2d363b <+171>: movq   %rbx, %rdi
    0x10a2d363e <+174>: movq   %r15, %rsi
    0x10a2d3641 <+177>: movq   %r14, %r8
    0x10a2d3644 <+180>: popq   %rbx
    0x10a2d3645 <+181>: popq   %r12
    0x10a2d3647 <+183>: popq   %r14
    0x10a2d3649 <+185>: popq   %r15
    0x10a2d364b <+187>: popq   %rbp
    0x10a2d364c <+188>: jmp    0x10a2cf310               ; CFStringCompareWithOptionsAndLocale
    0x10a2d3651 <+193>: nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)
```

The full stack trace looks like this:

```
  * thread #1: tid = 0x26780, 0x00000001024555a9 CoreFoundation`CFStringCompare + 25, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
  * frame #0: 0x00000001024555a9 CoreFoundation`CFStringCompare + 25
    frame #1: 0x000000010ddde349 CoreTelephony`sCTEventForNotificationString(__CFString const*) + 77
    frame #2: 0x000000010de15a80 CoreTelephony`_CTServerConnectionRegisterForNotification + 22
    frame #3: 0x000000010ddfdfab CoreTelephony`-[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo setUpServerConnection] + 215
    frame #4: 0x000000010ddfe250 CoreTelephony`-[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo init] + 257
    frame #5: 0x0000000102004d7c Mapbox`-[MGLMapboxEventsData init] + 588
    frame #6: 0x0000000102006be0 Mapbox`-[MGLMapboxEvents resumeMetricsCollection] + 416
    frame #7: 0x0000000102005aa0 Mapbox`-[MGLMapboxEvents init] + 2064
    frame #8: 0x0000000102006236 Mapbox`__32+[MGLMapboxEvents sharedManager]_block_invoke_2 + 38
    frame #9: 0x0000000105d8449b libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
    frame #10: 0x0000000105d6fe28 libdispatch.dylib`dispatch_once_f + 543
    frame #11: 0x00000001020061ff Mapbox`__32+[MGLMapboxEvents sharedManager]_block_invoke + 95
    frame #12: 0x000000010200611d Mapbox`+[MGLMapboxEvents sharedManager] + 221
    frame #13: 0x0000000102022a7c Mapbox`+[MGLAccountManager setAccessToken:] + 204
    frame #14: 0x000000010202267e Mapbox`+[MGLAccountManager load] + 222
    frame #15: 0x0000000104558dff libobjc.A.dylib`call_load_methods + 731
    frame #16: 0x0000000104559892 libobjc.A.dylib`load_images + 123
    frame #17: 0x0000000101e42a75
    frame #18: 0x0000000101e4d796
    frame #19: 0x0000000101e4d73b
    frame #20: 0x0000000101e4caba
    frame #21: 0x0000000101e4cb4f
    frame #22: 0x0000000101e42d79
    frame #23: 0x0000000101e45fed
    frame #24: 0x0000000101e42251
    frame #25: 0x00007fff6bb86656 dyld`dyld::useSimulatorDyld(int, macho_header const*, char const*, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 1702
    frame #26: 0x00007fff6bb8505c dyld`dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 208
    frame #27: 0x00007fff6bb81276 dyld`dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) + 512
    frame #28: 0x00007fff6bb81036 dyld`_dyld_start + 54
```

Comment: What does the call stack look like?

Comment: It reports: Thread 1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x0), and in thread 1, it has two: 0 CFStringCompare, 28 dyld_start. The debugger stopped at 0 CFStringCompare

Comment: It would probably be more readable if you added it to the question in a quote block.

Comment: It has been updated.

Comment: I do get a crash (not exactly the same one, but originating from a dispatch_once in MGLMapboxEvents sharedManager as well) even without Parse. Looks like there's a problem with the library they distribute (at least the version for the simulator). You may want to contact them.

Comment: Mapbox issue is easy to fix, you need to add a total of four keys to info.plist:  MGLMapboxMetricsEnabled, MGLMapboxMetricsEnabledSettingShownInApp, MGLMapboxAccessToken and NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription to it. The first two keys are not clearly stated in Mapbox documentation. Also in order to run Mapbox in swift you need to add a bridging header and change Objective - C Bridging Header value in Build Settings to where you store your bridging header.h file

Comment: I finally got it run. It is simply because Mapbox api needs CoreTelephony.framework to work together with Parse api. So simply link CoreTelephony.framework to Mapbox-iOS-SDK target in Pods project would solve my issue:)

Answer (score 1):

There's an issue around Core Telephony that's just been fixed and will surface in 3.0.1. In the meantime, you can avoid linking Core Telephony or you can install the preview release like so:

```
pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK', :podspec => 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/ios-v3.0.1-pre.1/ios/Mapbox-iOS-SDK.podspec'
```

More here: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/3112

Comment: I cannot make my code work in 3.0.1, the import argument does not recognize Mapbox or Parse api. Is there any solution for this? The only way to solve my problem is manually linking CoreTelephony to my Mapbox 3.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I just got it! 
If you installed these two api by CocoaPod, CocoaPod will link each of these two frameworks targets with corresponding libraries. **But one library must also present for Mapbox-iOS-SDK: CoreTelephony.** 
Click on **Pods** project then select the target as Mapbox-iOS-SDK, in Build Phases tab, go to Link Binary with Libraries and add CoreTelephony.framework for Mapbox. It should work fine.

Also, regarding the Mapbox SDK 3.0.0 api setup, a total of 2 keys should be added to info.plist:

- **MGLMapboxAccessToken** as String and value should be your Mapbox account token
- **NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription** as String and value is defined by your preference

If using swift, a bridging header should be created as any name you want, then adding following code to it (you don't need to import Parse in bridging header since only Mapbox is written in Objective-C):

```
#import <Mapbox/Mapbox.h>
```

Then change **Objective - C Bridging Header** value in **Build Settings** to path where you store your bridging header.h file(example: **Briding-Header.h**).

**NOTE:You need to make sure you store bridging header file under the project root folder. If not, you need to first specify which subfolder it is in.**

Finally, don't forget to import Mapbox and Parse at where you want to use it:

```
import Bolts
import Parse
import Mapbox
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `MGLMapboxMetricsEnabledSettingShownInApp` should only be used if you're actually providing this required setting in your app. See https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/#telemetry_opt_out for more details.